# Can't see files with Symlink

Tags: bash, debian, symlink

I need my client to be able to see the file in the directory they are allowed on. So I soft link the directory they are allowed on but can't see the files inside even tho they have the right (rwx).

ex:

```
/home/user1/project1.link/(couple of files)**

/clients/client_shamwow/project1/(couples of files)
```

**: Can't see the files.

This is the line I used:

```
ln -s /clients/client_shamwow/projet_prod /home/user1/projet_prod
```

is there something wrong that I am doing so they can't see the files in project_prod or I should use something else?

Comment: The user needs to be able to read and access the files in the directory (at least `r-x` permission on the directory) in `/clients/clientshamwow/project1`.  If they can't see the files, then either you have the wrong path in your symlink (it can be tricky with a relative path; absolute names aren't usually a problem unless you've got typos in them) or there's a permission problem somewhere along the line.  On most systems, the permissions on the symlink itself are not material.

Answer (score 0):

Your command doesn't match your example, but I assume you mean `/home/user1/project1.link` is a soft (symbolic) link, and when you run `ls` it lists just that name, rather than the contents of the directory the link points to. If that's the case, add the `-L` option to your `ls` command.

`ls -lL /home/user1/project1.link`

The man page says:

`-L, --dereference
   when  showing  file  information for a symbolic link, show information
   for the file the link references rather than for the link itself`

Another way is simply to append `/.` to the end of your command, as in

`ls -l /home/user1/project1.link/.`

If that doesn't answer your question, I think you need to be more clear, and perhaps clean up the inconsistencies in your question. Even show some real output and the commands you ran.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. No idea what happend. I just recreated the link the exact same way I did before and now I am able to see AND modify the files as the user1 w/o him being able to go anywhere else than what is in the folder `project_prod`. Thx for your time :)